# pyVisa too slow with RS232

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, pyvisa

Simple program:

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
list=rm.list_resources()
print(list) # list[0] is RS-232 reference
my_instrument = rm.open_resource(list[0])
print(my_instrument.query('*IDN?'))
#it works fine until this point, asking for one line of text only.
print(my_instrument.query('CURVE?'))
#After this oscilloscope is sending lots of data (1000 digits formatted as strings).
```

I get:

In python 3.4

> "VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation
>   completed."

In python 3.6

> VI_ERROR_ASRL_OVERRUN "An overrun error occurred during transfer. A
>   character was not read from the hardware before the next character
>   arrived.

As far as I know, pyVisa is reading too slow when compare to speed of data sending. Same procedure is working when I am using pyVisa/GPIB, or pySerial/COM.

How can I make it faster, or what can I do to get that data by pyVisa/COM?

Comment: did u check if the baud rate of the sending device is same as the receiving?